# How to bind a parameter inside of a LIKE clause with percentages in mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using `mysqli`, and I have this query:

```
$q = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM `Something` WHERE col2 LIKE '%?%'";
```

The same query works fine if I query it outside of PHP with a word in place of `?`. Within PHP, I can't do this. The error I'm getting is:

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement[..]

The query is outputting fine in `var_dump()`, as is the parameter itself.

Here's the `bind_param()`:

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `LIKE ?` then add the percentages to the actual param

Comment: @JimL ...I can't believe how simple that was, and that I hadn't thought of it, lol. That's perfect. If you'd like to post it as an answer, it will be accepted.

Comment: I'm sure it's a duplicate, hopefully someone can tag it - for some weird reason I had trouble finding a duplicate

Comment: I was not able to find a duplicate, hence the post. Suggestions were for PDO, and the answers didn't work with mysqli.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just a matter of placement of the signs

```
$q = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM `Something` WHERE col2 LIKE ?";

$stmt->bind_param("s", '%' . $param . '%');
```

I know this has thrown off a lot of people, you're not the first :)

Comment: Note that if your PHP configuration is set to throw an error when passing parameters by value when references are expected (which I think should be recommended), then you need to create a temporary variable and pass it as shown by Justin in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52898138/1652488) because bind_param expects references.

Answer (score 3):

To get this working I had to do this (similar to the correct answer)...

```
$param = '%' . $param . '%'

$q = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM `Something` WHERE col2 LIKE ?";

$stmt->bind_param("s", $param );
```

Comment: This works just as well as the answer by JimL

Comment: @Nerdi.org In fact, storing in a temporary variable is necessary because bind_param() expects references to be passed, not values - it even throws an error in some versions/configurations.